# Salesforce Report - Field Not Populating Within Report

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Hope you're well. I'm currently building out a report, but despite my best efforts so far, I can't get some information to populate within the report. It does not appear to me that salesforce is recognizing the field "Agent Incoming Connecting Time" within the object "AC_Agent_Performance". However, I can pull in some other fields within the same object into the Agent Performance report, so I'm not clear on what is not taking place in the field that I wish to see within the report. Here are some of the things that I've tried:

1. I have checked the access to the field. The first photo (Photo 1) Shows an example of a working object, the the second one shows an example of one that does not.[image]
   [image]
2. The API name seems to work, and is consistent with other fields within the object that work.
3. I have checked the page layout for the object (even though I don't think this is the issue), and I have mirrored other fields to the best of my knowledge that ARE populating within the report.
4. I reviewed the CTI flows to see if there was something missing in there on a lark, but there was nothing in there that would lead me to believe that this was the source of the problem.
5. I have tried setting up a new field in the object (formula), that references the field that I'm trying. to pull in, but that just returns a result of 'zero' for all values.

One thing that I have done that appears to be working, is I have set up a joined report, which uses both "AC Agent Performance" object and "AC Historical Queue Metrics" object in the report. The result that is returning appears to be accurate (please see the picture (picture number 3)[image]). However, I don't think that this is the right way to go about this, and I don't want to do it this way. I want to use the report with one object rather than with two.

I know that permissions are the most likely issue, so I've taken a close look at these. Please let me know if there is something wrong with how I have the permissions configured. The First image depicts the 'Field Level Security'. The second image depicts the'field accessibility'. They are both like this, the whole way down:

[image]
[image]

Please note one other thing, which is that the last picture depicts a different field within the object displaying in the report.

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can proceed so the field "Agent Incoming Connecting Time" will display within the report?

Please also note, that these are objects that contain data that is populated from AWS' Amazon Connect.

This last photo, shows that the object does not have any information in it within the report.

[image]

Comment: Little help would be nice!

Comment: Do you actually have non-zero values in "AC Agent Performance.Agent Incoming Connecting Time" records. Because your joined report looks like pulling data from another object that happens to have a field with same name.

Comment: Yes, they're all dashes. Let me post a photo for you.

Comment: Hi eyescream. Please see the photo that I added for your review. Do you need any other information?

Comment: I've posted some ideas. In current form your question isn't very coding-related - try posting on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/, might end up seen by more admins, maybe more people who have used this package...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that. I'll give it a swing over there.

Comment: Reposted question within salesforce stack overflow. Will continue to monitor answers here as well as there.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/363521/field-not-populating-within-report

Answer (score 0):

If the field isn't populated there's not much you can do on the reporting side of things. You already tried "joined report". You should check why the integration doesn't populate it, maybe read integration documentation, contact the managed package's support...

The tables are connected with lookup or master-detail, right? In a pinch you could try making formula field on "AC Agent Performance" looking "up" and pulling the value from related AC historical queue metrics. If the relationship is other way around (performance -> down to related list -> metrics) you could try to make-do with a master detail and rollup summary field. I don't know this package, no idea if you can pull it off when you don't have full control over the fields.

If you can't really use the relationships and absolutely need to report on single table - you could capture intermediate results of the report to a helper table and then report on that. It's called ["reporting snapshots"](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_about_analytic_snap.htm&type=5). Or write some nightly (hourly?) batch that recalculates stuff and writes homemade "rollup" to these fields?